# Wifi connected but not working

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am creating an android app which relies on the internet. How do I handle the case in which the phone is connected to the Wifi but it is not actually working? 
As in the case when there is an exclamation mark next to the wifi icon in the `StatusBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Try this mehod :

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            urlc.connect();
            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                return new Boolean(true);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect wifi speed and if the speed is very low then you can handle the situation.

First, check if your connection type is wifi-

```
 ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
 boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
 activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
 boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;

 if(isWifi){
     WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManger.getConnectionInfo();
     int mbps = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
 }
```